# How can I sort stacked bar chart by a specific category?

Tags: looker-studio

How do I sort a field (`Status OMR`) in the following stacked bar chart with the rightmost category in grey (values are "*Belum selesai*") in ascending order (from lowest to highest)? It currently sorts by the leftmost category in darkest orange (values called "*OMR diterima*").

Stacked bar chart created in Google Data Studio:

[image]

This is how the bar chart is currently sorted (5 rows shown to demonstrate; 16 rows in the linked data set):

| Malaysia | OMR diterima | OMR telah dipos | Tinjauan selesai | Belum selesai |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KELANTAN | 4 | 1 | 4 | 7 |
| JOHOR | 2 | 1 | 1 | 12 |
| KEDAH | 1 |  | 10 | 5 |
| NEGERI SEMBILAN | 1 | 1 |  | 14 |
| PULAU PINANG | 1 | 3 | 2 | 10 |

I want the chart to be sorted like:

| Malaysia | OMR diterima | OMR telah dipos | Tinjauan selesai | Belum selesai |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NEGERI SEMBILAN | 1 | 1 |  | 14 |
| JOHOR | 2 | 1 | 1 | 12 |
| PULAU PINANG | 1 | 3 | 2 | 10 |
| KELANTAN | 4 | 1 | 4 | 7 |
| KEDAH | 1 |  | 10 | 5 |

I followed this [guide](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/45098070/sorting-stacked-bar-chart?hl=en) to arrange the categories in the desired (horizontal) order across a single stacked bar, and created the [calculated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685):

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Status OMR, "(?i)OMR diterima") THEN 4
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Status OMR, "(?i)OMR telah dipos") THEN 3
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Status OMR, "(?i)Tinjauan selesai") THEN 2
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Status OMR, "(?i)Belum selesai") THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

[Data Set (Google Sheets)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DRYDLR-lNsKGXVgwAUER2Q65gVCf04nL2fYLvx6ImwI/edit?usp=sharing) (9 rows shown below to demonstrate; 240 rows in the linked data set):

| Malaysia | Status OMR |
| --- | --- |
| JOHOR | OMR diterima |
| JOHOR | Tinjauan selesai |
| JOHOR | OMR diterima |
| JOHOR | OMR telah dipos |
| JOHOR | Belum selesai |
| JOHOR | Belum selesai |
| JOHOR | Belum selesai |
| JOHOR | Belum selesai |
| JOHOR | Belum selesai |

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/dcb64573-d9e7-40a0-a527-4c27a54805de)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by creating the [calculated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below in the **Sort** of the [bar chart](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7165560), which uses the [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) function to capture instances of the grey coloured values, by searching for the phrase "*Belum selesai*" in the `Status OMR` field, and subsequently utilising the [`COUNT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583207) function to aggregate the field. Then set the order to **Ascending** to ensure that the chart is sorted starting with the lowest [`COUNT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583207) of the grey coloured values:

```
COUNT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Status OMR, "Belum selesai"))
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/e88a8fc6-7c1a-4d2a-97f2-27aa35350c5b) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o01wS0VkTgYbE75U0UaFkJhduej3FCAmh3a7boyYCPs/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: 7]